# Angular rootScope works then goes undefined on refresh - AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, angularfire

Scenario: I assign some values for the user at login to my `rootScope`. Now I want to able to use those values so that every time the user post a meeting, it should be added under his information in Firebase db.

Issue: I do this well, when I login, and i post the meeting from the user. But then as soon as the page refreshes, `rootScope.currentUser` becomes undefined. How can I keep rootScope.currentUser from going undefined? My Controller and my factory are below:

my controller:

```
myApp.controller('MeetingsController', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $rootScope, FIREBASE_URL, SomeURL){

    //rootScope.currentUser.$id works the first time i post then the second it doesn't
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + $rootScope.currentUser.$id + SomeURL);
    var meetings = $firebaseObject(ref);
    $scope.meetings = meetings;

    $scope.addMeeting = function(){
        ref.push({
          name: $scope.meetingname,
          date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
       });
    };
});//controller for around me
```

My Factory:

```
myApp.factory('Authentification', function($firebase, $rootScope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth, $routeParams, $location, FIREBASE_URL){   

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
    auth.$onAuth(function(authUser){
        if(authUser){
            var firebaseUsers = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/users/'+authUser.uid);
            var  user       = $firebaseObject(firebaseUsers);
            $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        } else {
            $rootScope.currentUser = '';
        }
    });
    var myObject = {
        login: function(user){
            return auth.$authWithPassword({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.pswd
            });
        }, 
        logout: function(user){
            return auth.$unauth();
        },
        requireAuth: function() {
            return auth.$requireAuth();
        }
    };
    return myObject;
});
```

Route:

```
myApp.config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html', 
            controller: 'RegistrationController' 
        }).
        when('/register',{
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
            controller: 'RegistrationController' 
        }).
        when('/aroundme', {
            templateUrl: 'views/aroundme.html' ,
            controller: 'MeetingsController', 
            resolve: {
                currentAuth: function(Authentification){
                    return Authentification.requireAuth();
                }
            }
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Can you post your routing please?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz alright in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that you're assigning the `$firebaseObject` to the `$rootScope` before it has finished loading. To make sure that it has loaded before binding it to the `$rootScope` use `$loaded()`:

```
auth.$onAuth(function(authUser){
    if(authUser){
        var firebaseUsers = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/users/'+authUser.uid);
        var  user       = $firebaseObject(firebaseUsers);

        user.$loaded()
          .then(function(data) {
            $rootScope.currentUser = data;
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            // Handle error
        });
    } else {
        $rootScope.currentUser = '';
    }
});
```

From [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject):

> Note that the data will not be available immediately since retrieving it is an asynchronous operation. You can use the $loaded() promise to get notified when the data has loaded.

Comment: same issue. My belief is: the problem is coming from rootScope. It works the first time then the second time it doesn't work . I have to logout and log back in. It seems not holding the value.

Comment: What happens if you set it to the regular scope? That's how I have it then I've made the $onAuth call in my mainctrl and set it as an attribute on the html tag to always be available.